# UDP Client after several send/receives stops receiving and blocks port

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to send and receive to/from a UDP multicast address using UWP. It works perfectly the first few times, but after a while of this send-receive process, it will lock on the receiving part. I changed from an async approach to a synchronous one but still the same. Even if I instantiate a new UDP client, the port is blocked until the app is restarted. Anything I'm doing wrong?

```
private UdpClient udp; 
//inside main function:
 if (udp == null)
        {
            udp = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNumber));
            //^the second time this is called, it will complain about port reuse
            udp.Client.ReceiveTimeout = udp.Client.SendTimeout = 3000;
            //udp.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            //^invalid 
        }

        //await udp.SendAsync(data, data.Length, , portNumber);
        //I changed from async to synchronous in case it was the issue, but no.
        udp.Client.SendTo(data, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipString), portNumber));
        //the receive used to be async, too
        byte[] receivedByte = new byte[udp.Client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        try
        {
            udp.Client.Receive(receivedByte);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            udp.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            udp = null; // added these, but port still blocked until restart
        }
```

I'm using UWP, and there are methods on class library that aren't here.

Comment: Do you think there can be an issue related to backlog, or limited number of sockets allowed to open!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful don't know but don't think so...I guess it's possible it could be an external issue...

Comment: Could you please a minimal sample to help us reproduce your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the initiative @GraceFeng-MSFT , but I may have the answer already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting UdpClient in a using () statement instead of declaring it as a private field, and limiting its scope by putting it in a short async method, I am not having these problems anymore.